# Subdomain redirection for invalid SSL certificate

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have bought an SSL certificate which is valid only for domain.com and www.domain.com. Unfortunately there are a number of links out their beyond my control which point to m.domain.com. As the certificate is not valid for subdomains they are seeing an invalid certificate popup.

What is the best way to rewrite https://m.domain.com URLs so that they point to https://domain.com? (please notice it is only necessary to do this for httpS)

I have tried the following with no success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If you remove the `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` does it work?

Comment: This is useless. The browser will get the 301-redirect, because it get's it from a server with an incorrect certificate, so it will not even send the request. Just make sure no-one uses https to link m.domain.com/

Comment: @Gerben, thanks for your feedback. So basically there is no solution other than trying to get rid of the m.domain.com links, right?

Comment: not all the `m.domain.com`, just the `https://m.domain.com` ones, as only those don't work.

Comment: Why not buy a wildcart certificate? Nowadays they are pretty cheap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it cannot be done...